# Difficulty reverse engineering CRC 16

Tags: reverse-engineering, crc16

I have captured 3 packets that I think all use the same 16 bit CRC, but I can't find a common match. They are:
1. DB97BD7F85C7
2. DCC45CDFBF47
3. DB5BF51FA66F

Running reveng on all 3 produces no match. But I get a match for just 1 and 2, 1 and 3, and 2 and 3. I also have the SRP16 matches below, with similar results. I assume the numerous partial matches from SRP16 makes a great example of why [Ross Williams](http://www.zlib.net/crc_v3.txt) and others say to NEVER make up your own poly unless you know what you're doing. I will post more if I make any progress.

What am I missing?

Here is what I tried:

1, 2 and 3

```
>reveng -w 16 -s DB97BD7F85C7 DCC45CDFBF47 DB5BF51FA66F
reveng: no models found
```

1 and 2

```
>reveng -w 16 -s DB97BD7F85C7 DCC45CDFBF47
width=16  poly=0x1c4d  init=0x0820  refin=false  refout=false xorout=0x0000  check=0xe5a3  name=(none)
width=16  poly=0x5313  init=0x0541  refin=false  refout=false  xorout=0x0000  check=0x16ee  name=(none)
```

width=16  poly=0xd84d  init=0xcbb0  refin=false  refout=false  xorout=0x0000  check=0xd81f  name=(none)

1 and 3

```
>reveng -w 16 -s DB97BD7F85C7 DB5BF51FA66F
width=16  poly=0xcfdb  init=0x2152  refin=false  refout=false  xorout=0x0000  check=0x7c5f  name=(none)
```

2 and 3

```
>reveng -w 16 -s DCC45CDFBF47 DB5BF51FA66F
width=16  poly=0x6319  init=0xce07  refin=false  refout=false  xorout=0x0000  check=0x358f  name=(none)
```

For what its worth, I also ran an exhaustive search with SRP16. As you can see, SRP16 found several matches for 1 and 3, and 2 and 3 (it only searches for Data 1, then checks the other 2). These are the results:

```
===== Result parameter sets =====
CRC=$c791  Poly=$0a1f  init=$51a7  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=true 
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$c791  Poly=$0a1f  init=$560a  xorout=$0000  refin=false  refout=true 
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$24ab  init=$4b77  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$24ab  init=$f978  xorout=$0000  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$32c1  init=$58d2  xorout=$0000  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$32c1  init=$e604  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$4078  init=$19b0  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$4078  init=$31bf  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$4078  init=$49ae  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$4078  init=$61a1  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$4078  init=$9183  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$4078  init=$b98c  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$4078  init=$c19d  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$4078  init=$e992  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$45cf  init=$12de  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$45cf  init=$78e7  xorout=$0000  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$4928  init=$0e97  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$4928  init=$27b2  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$4928  init=$5cdd  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$4928  init=$75f8  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$4928  init=$8326  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$4928  init=$aa03  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$4928  init=$d16c  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$4928  init=$f849  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$5b2b  init=$d6b6  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$5b2b  init=$fa7d  xorout=$0000  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$5ff8  init=$0056  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$5ff8  init=$2ba9  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$5ff8  init=$57a8  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$5ff8  init=$7c57  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$5ff8  init=$8455  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$5ff8  init=$afaa  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$5ff8  init=$d3ab  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$5ff8  init=$f854  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$c791  Poly=$701f  init=$c9e9  xorout=$0000  refin=false  refout=true 
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$c791  Poly=$701f  init=$fa7c  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=true 
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$c791  Poly=$723b  init=$4239  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$c791  Poly=$723b  init=$da97  xorout=$0000  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$7296  init=$6f03  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$7296  init=$d648  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$7598  init=$1faf  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$7598  init=$311c  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$7598  init=$42c9  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$7598  init=$6c7a  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$7598  init=$8bd0  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$7598  init=$a563  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$7598  init=$d6b6  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$7598  init=$f805  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$868a  init=$12de  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$868a  init=$d19b  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$9232  init=$1faf  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$9232  init=$d6b6  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$a4df  init=$0bee  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$a4df  init=$1a23  xorout=$0000  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$c791  Poly=$aa75  init=$16df  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=true 
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$c791  Poly=$aa75  init=$c58b  xorout=$0000  refin=true   refout=true 
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$c732  init=$4b77  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$c732  init=$a8ee  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$cbdd  init=$6f03  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$cbdd  init=$8ec3  xorout=$0000  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$cf54  init=$311c  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$cf54  init=$42c9  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$cf54  init=$a563  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$cf54  init=$d6b6  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$c791  Poly=$d143  init=$2b44  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=true 
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$c791  Poly=$d143  init=$754a  xorout=$0000  refin=true   refout=true 
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$e044  init=$19b0  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$e044  init=$61a1  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$e044  init=$9183  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$e044  init=$e992  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=false
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$ea2e  init=$1ec6  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=true 
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$ea2e  init=$ebd1  xorout=$ffff  refin=false  refout=true 
 *** Second data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$edbc  init=$27b2  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$edbc  init=$5cdd  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$edbc  init=$aa03  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
CRC=$91c7  Poly=$edbc  init=$d16c  xorout=$ffff  refin=true   refout=false
 *** Third  data set verified
===== done =====
```

Comment: You're going to need to capture a lot more packets than three. If you can provide a few dozen, then maybe we can get somewhere.

Comment: Still being new to CRCs, does SRP16 not search for every possible combination of parameters?

Comment: I don't know what SRP16 searches. There are several ways for the CRC to be encoded at the end, if that is a CRC at the end.